# check for last number of users logged in to machine?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to come up with a powershell script thatcan determine the last number of users that logged on to a machine. I'm stuck on to how to approach it. If I'm correct, using a get-wmiobject call will only get the last user. I'm wondering if maybe there is a call I can do to get the history of something like the user folder and get the last users that modified that?Or is there some simpler way?

Comment: I would think that looking for logins in the security event log would be the way to go, but I've never tried this myself.

Comment: I'll try seeing if that is linked to power shell somehow.

Comment: There are several methods for getting the event logs in PS. I just don't remember what you would look for in the logs. At a PS prompt, type get-help *event*

Comment: Yeah. I just got it. Thanks! Wanna post an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: I don't have the time right now to post a decent answer. I would suggest that you write up what you did and post that as an answer. Then in a few days you will be able to accept it and then users with similar questions will be able to find a nice answer.

Comment: I need to start using this more. I don't have enough rep to do that for another 6 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, all user logins are saved in the security log of each windows server. These are set in the log with the following eventIDs: 528 and 540. These two IDs are for a direct or a remote login to a machine. For my specific need, I have to following line in my script. If you have a similar need, be sure to read up on windows eventIDs on a site like [this one](http://www.eventID.net/)

```
Get-EventLog -logname security -ComputerName $svr -Newest 100 | where {$_.eventID -eq 528
-or 540} | select time,user
```

enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverpowershell/thread/c61dc944-6c40-4ab8-93f8-8c345c37b0d4