# Get all users who were logged into a computer

Tags: powershell

I can retrieve the currently logged in user to a machine by using

```
$machine = "<computer_name>"
Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $machine| Select-Object Name,UserName
```

Is there any way, to get ALL users who where logged into this machine, including the time the user was logged in?

Comment: You'd need to parse the event log 'Security', look for logon events, then retrieve username and date / time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check for last number of users logged in to machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023838/check-for-last-number-of-users-logged-in-to-machine)

Comment: But be aware: The solution of the duplicate question might not get ALL users, because the EventLog works like a ringbuffer, i.e. there is only a certain number of events logged and not all events for all time.

Comment: Not too much you can do there, unfortunately, unless you also pull the users from C:\Users, then pull the last modified date and use this as a benchmark.